# R/dplyr: Replace row values based on two conditions, keep all others as they are

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that has a variable fruit and a owner. 
Input:

```
ID  Fruit       Owner
1   apple       Jane
2   orange      Jane's dog
3   cherry      John
4   apple       John's cat
5   orange      John
6   cherry      Jane's dog
```

I want to rename all values in the fruit column if two conditions across the fruit and owner column are met; the fruit is NOT an apple, and the owner contains a `'` symbol. I want the end result to look like this:

```
ID  Fruit       Owner
1   apple       Jane
2   carrot      Jane's dog
3   cherry      John
4   apple       John's cat
5   orange      John
6   carrot      Jane's dog
```

I tried using dplyr, but this data snippet drops all other rows that are not met by the conditions. I need to keep all rows, and merely replace the values in those where the two conditions are met:

```
qx2 <- qx %>%
    dplyr::filter(grepl("'", Owner)) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(Fruit != "apple") %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(Fruit = "carrot")
```

I also tried this snippet, which doesn't do anything at all:

```
qx2$Fruit[qx2$Fruit== "apple" & qx2$Owner == grepl("'", qx2$Owner)] = "carrot"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the vectorized ifelse

```
library(dplyr)
    qx %>%
       mutate(Fruit = ifelse(Fruit != "apple" & grepl("'", Owner), "carrot", Fruit))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to run that code, but I get the following error message: 
    
```Error: Column `Fruit` can't be converted from integer to character```

- which is weird because the column is a factor. I also tried to convert the column to character with `as.character()`, but I still get the same error message. How can I fix this?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it by mutating the column as character first within the dplyr pipes: 
```qx2 <- qx %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Fruit= as.character(Fruit)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Fruit= ifelse(Fruit!= "apple" & grepl("'", Owner), "carrot", Fruit))```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!